# Creating a class without creating an instance in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

How can I write this code in php?

```
Database::select("podomoro")->table("blog")->get();
```

or

```
Database::table("blog")->select("podomoro")->get();
```

Second method may change, after database class.

Comment: Open laravel sources and see.

Comment: You actually shouldn't write either of those. Because each of those lines has multiple anti-patterns.

Comment: @u_mulder "learn from laravel" is both destructive for a newbie and in-general dumb suggestion.

Comment: Is there a short way without laravel ?  Laravel too complicated

Comment: @tereško - maybe not antipatterns as such. Static class methods and fluent interfaces all have it's uses. Of course, thery are too oftem misused and exploited. Nevertheless they can be useful.

Comment: @TomaszStruczyński in my experience, for the newbie-to-intermediate level developers, it is better to go with *hyperbole*, instead of extremely detailed and nuanced explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I'll split this code into lines:

```
Database::select("podomoro")
    ->table("blog")
    ->get();
```

The first line essentially calls a static method of a class Database. This static method returns an object instance (probably - kind of SELECT object). This object has method `table()` (probably among many others).

On the second line you are calling `table()` method of an object returned in first line. This method does something and returns another object instance. This is used for 'fluent' interfaces, when you can make a method calls chain.

Third line calls a method `get()` on an object returned from function called in second line.

The simplest implementation of this will be:

```
<?php

class Database
{
    public static function select($something)
    {
        // Do something meaningfull
        return new Query();
    }
}

class Query
{
    public function table($name)
    {
        // Do something meaningfull
        return $this;
    }

    public function get()
    {
        // Do something meaningfull

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**BUT**, as others mentioned in comments, this pattern is often overused and - in fact - often becomes an anti-pattern. For modern frameworks (like Symfony2 etc) you should rather use Dependency Injection and service instances.

Fluent interfaces are also discouraged. You should use them mostly when implementing `builder` pattern - eg. `QueryBuilder` in Doctrine etc.

As for me I do not recommend using static class methods if you do not know, what you are doing. I'm using them primarily to overload class constructors (I create private class constructor and several static methods with different parameters used to create class instance). Lately I have used it, when integrating DI into old framework without such capabilities - DI object itself was a singleton and had a static `getInstance()` method. I'm not very proud of it, though.

Comment: I personally would advise to instead write custom [data mappers](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html).

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to this question. @tomasz-struczyński's method is true too.

```
    class PhoneNumber
    {
        protected $number;
        protected $countries = [];
        protected $country;
        public function __construct($number)
        {
            $this->number = $number;                
        }

        public static function make($number, $country = [])
        {
            $instance = new static($number);
            return $instance->ofCountry($country);
        }

        public function ofCountry($country)
        {
            $countries = is_array($country) ? $country : func_get_args();
            $instance = clone $this;
            $instance->countries = array_unique(array_merge($instance->countries, $countries));
            return $instance;
        }
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    $dd=PhoneNumber::make(100,"TR")->ofCountry('BE');
    print_r($dd);
```